# Managed Extensible framework - unable to use mef when two classes implement one interface

Tags: c#, mef

I have one interface and two class implements this interface.I am not able to use MEF concept in this situation. My code is below. Please help me with converting the same using MEF.

```
 public interface IResultsRepository
    {
        IList<string> GetResults();
        string GetSummary();
    }

[Export(typeof(IResultsRepository))]
public class ExcelResultsRepository : IResultsRepository
{
    private readonly string filePath;
    private readonly string worksheetName;
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ExcelResultsRepository([Import("FilePath")]string filePath, [Import("WorkSheetName")]string worksheetName)
    {
        this.filePath = filePath;
        this.worksheetName = worksheetName;
    }
    public IList<string> GetResults()
    {
    }
    public string GetSummary()
    {
    }
}

[Export(typeof(IResultsRepository))]
public class ResultsFormRepository : IResultsRepository
{
    private readonly ResultForm resultForm;
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ResultsFormRepository([Import("ResultFormInstance")]ResultForm resultForm)
    {
        this.resultForm = resultForm;
    }
    public IList<string> GetResults()
    {

    }
    public string GetSummary()
    {
    }
}

[Export("ResultFormInstance")]
public class ResultForm
{
    public string Tables
    {
        get { return ""; }
    }

    public string Summary
    {
        get
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
}

[Export]
public class ResultsContentConverter
{
    private readonly IResultsRepository resultRepository;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ResultsContentConverter([Import(typeof(IResultsRepository))]IResultsRepository resultRepository)
    {
        this.resultRepository = resultRepository;
    }

    public ResultContent GetResultContent()
    {
        //logic to convert the format and return formatted object containg results and summary
    }
}

[TestFixture]
[Export]
public class ResultComapreTest
{
    [Import] 
    private ResultsContentConverter excelContentConverter;

    [Import("ResultFormConverter", typeof(IResultsRepository))]
    private ResultsContentConverter resultFormContentConverter;

    [Test]
    public void CompareResultFromResultForm()
    {
        ResultContent expectedResult;
        ResultContent actualResult;

        using (IResultsRepository excelResultsRepository = new ExcelResultsRepository(@"C:\Users\akuma211\Abhineet\Project\Sample\UnityContainerLearning\Sample\book1.xlsx", "sheet1"))
        {
            var converter = new ResultsContentConverter(excelResultsRepository);

            expectedResult = converter.GetResultContent();
        }

        using (IResultsRepository resultsRepository = new ResultsFormRepository(new ResultForm()))
        {
            var converter = new ResultsContentConverter(resultsRepository);

            actualResult = converter.GetResultContent();
        }

        Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult.Summary, actualResult.Summary);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult.Tables[0].Rows.Count, actualResult.Tables[0].Rows.Count);
    }
}
```

In the test method I should be using MEF. Please help me

Thanks

Hi I am editing the test method below as I wanted.

```
[Test]
        public void CompareResultFromResultForm()
        {
            ResultContent expectedResult;
            ResultContent actualResult;

            Compose();// MEF composer, that composes my ResultsContentConverter object
            //using (IResultsRepository excelResultsRepository = new ExcelResultsRepository(@"C:\Users\akuma211\Abhineet\Project\Sample\UnityContainerLearning\Sample\book1.xlsx", "sheet1"))
            //{
            //    var converter = new ResultsContentConverter(excelResultsRepository);

            //    expectedResult = converter.GetResultContent();
            //}
            expectedResult = excelContentConverter.GetResultContent();

            //using (IResultsRepository resultsRepository = new ResultsFormRepository(new ResultForm()))
            //{
            //    var converter = new ResultsContentConverter(resultsRepository);

            //    actualResult = converter.GetResultContent();
            //}
            actualResult = resultFormContentConverter.GetResultContent();

            Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult.Summary, actualResult.Summary);
            Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult.Tables[0].Rows.Count, actualResult.Tables[0].Rows.Count);
        }
```

HI I used importmany and did this as below

```
ResultContent expectedResult;
            ResultContent actualResult;

            var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
            container.ComposeExportedValue<string>("FilePath", @"C:\Users\akuma211\Abhineet\Project\Sample\UnityContainerLearning\Sample\book1.xlsx");
            container.ComposeExportedValue<string>("WorkSheetName", "sheet1");
            container.ComposeExportedValue<ResultForm>("ResultFormInstance", new ResultForm());

            container.ComposeParts(this);
            //ResultComapreTest obj = container.GetExportedValue<ResultComapreTest>();

            foreach (IResultsRepository rep in repository)
            {
                var converter = new ResultsContentConverter(rep);
                converter.GetResultContent();
            }
```

But I do not want to create the ResultsContentConverter object using new.
Instead of foreach I used

```
using (IResultsRepository excelResultsRepository = (repository.Where(rep => rep.GetType() == typeof(ExcelResultsRepository)).Select(rep => rep).First()))
            {
                var converter = new ResultsContentConverter(excelResultsRepository);

                expectedResult = converter.GetResultContent();
            }

            using (IResultsRepository resultsRepository = (repository.Where(rep => rep.GetType() == typeof(ResultsFormRepository)).Select(rep => rep).First()))
            {
                var converter = new ResultsContentConverter(resultsRepository);

                actualResult = converter.GetResultContent();
            }

            Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult.Summary, actualResult.Summary);
            Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult.Tables[0].Rows.Count, actualResult.Tables[0].Rows.Count);
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Can you explain what *exactly* your problem is? Do you get errors? Compile-time or runtime? What error message? Are your asserts failing?

Comment: I wanted my resultcontentconverter object to be created using mef

Comment: Ok, that's what you want. What did you try? What happened? What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: I have ResultsContentConverter class which takes IResultrepository parameter in constructor. There it has two class inheriting IresultRepoitory. I am not able to create object for ResultsContentConverter so that it takes both repository class as in test method. Can you update my code using mef.

Comment: Can you describe what you *expect* to happen? You have a single constructor and a single parameter. And two choices what to fill in. How do you want this problem solved? Can you describe it in plain text?

Answer (score 0):

Of course mef gives you a composition exception. 
You are giving two implementations of the same interface to the framework. How is MEF able to detect which implementation you want at that point?

You can work around this and use [ImportMany] which will basically import all available implementations of your IResultsRepository interface.

You will get a list of available implementations which you can cycle through to find the one you want to unit test.

For more information please refer to this pages:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.importmanyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.de/2010/04/very-basic-mef-sample-using-importmany.html

A quick example:
Having your interface:

```
    public interface IResultsRepository
{
    IList<string> GetResults();
    string GetSummary();
}
```

and two classes implementing this interface:

```
[Export(typeof(IResultsRepository))]
class CustomResultContainer : IResultsRepository
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public CustomResultContainer(IDoNothing nothing)
    {
    }

    public IList<string> GetResults()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string GetSummary()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

[Export(typeof(IResultsRepository))]
class ResultContainerWithLogging : IResultsRepository
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ResultContainerWithLogging(ILogger logger)
    {

    }

    public IList<string> GetResults()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string GetSummary()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Note that the constructors differ from each other, each class is dependent on a different interface (which represents your use case). Bot interfaces get injected by mef. You can find this part here:

```
    [Export(typeof(ILogger))]
class VoidLogger : ILogger
{
    public void Log()
    {
        Console.Write("Void Logging");
    }
}

[Export(typeof(IDoNothing))]
class DoNothingStub : IDoNothing
{
    public void doNothing()
    {

    }
}

interface ILogger
{
    void Log();
}

interface IDoNothing
{
    void doNothing();
}
```

Now composing all of this together:

```
        private void startup()
    {
        var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        container.ComposeParts(this);

        foreach (var resultsRepository in this.repositories)
        {
            Debugger.Break();
        }
    }

    [ImportMany]
    public List<IResultsRepository> repositories { get; set; }
}
```

This will give me exactl two elements in the List of irepositories because MEF found two implementations and injected them for me.

Comment: I was trying the same. but those two class has an importing constructor with different parameter for the two implementor class of repository - ResultsFormRepository, ExcelResultsRepository. I tried using  private IEnumerable<IResultsRepository> repository; but how do I compose this with parameter.

Comment: I do not see any example of importmany where there is constructor parameter of different datatype

Comment: but I have ResultsContentConverter class having IResultRepository as constructor parameter. How do I create object for this ResultsContentConverter  as you see in my test class

Comment: @Xeun, I have a scenario where I have multiple implementations of MEF in a DLL. And I need to instantiate one class of the class and I don't want to instantiate the other classes. Then what should be the proper way to do this?